# What is the purpose of user agent node-fetch fetching just the base URL from our site?

Tags: google, user-agent, github

The user agent `node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)`
has been fetching the base URL from IP's belonging to
`251.232.178.107.gae.googleusercontent.com`.

It is fairly aggressive and coming in from quite a number of IP addresses and I'm wondering why the user agent only fetches the base URL and no other resources are loaded.

[image: user agent]

I'd like to block it but am not sure it would be wise.

Comment: It looks like fetch-node is just a programming API for getting webpages using the node.js JavaScript framework.   Not sure we'll be able to answer this from just the information you provide.

Comment: Roughly once an hour? Some kind of health check or liveness check maybe? The originator hasn't done the favour of identifying themselves with the user agent so all you can do is block it if you don't like it.